# What's the best option for encrypting a file with openssl and a password?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, openssl, aes

I'm using a command to encrypt and decrypt files based on a password:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in secrets.txt -out secrets.txt.enc --pass pass:mypassword
```

and

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -in secrets.txt.enc -out secrets.txt.new -pass pass:mypassword
```

Someone had mentioned that this may be susceptible to brute force attacks (to try and decrypt the file via a password).

Is there a safer/better way to encrypt a file with a password than this? a -pbkdf2 option was also mentioned, but I can't seem to find much on it.

I was under the impression that AES-256 with salt was a really good option to choose for password encrypting a file.

If the password is long and very complex, would that also help the situation?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files/61166202#61166202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The *best option?* Don't use openssl, use gpg instead

Apparently your command uses the `enc` command (even though openssl's man page doesn't even mention `aes-256-cbc` at all, and `openssl help` outputs to stderr so simply piping it to less is a chore, also FYI it has an undocumented `-v` feature) and it leave *a lot* to be desired, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28248800/3412074) for more details, but they're basically:

- Non-standard encryption format.
- No indication of the encryption algorithm; you are supposed to keep track of that yourself.
- > The process by which the password and salt are turned into the key and IV is not documented, but a look at the source code shows that it calls the OpenSSL-specific [EVP_BytesToKey()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) function, which uses a custom [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) with some repeated hashing. This is a non-standard and not-well vetted construct (!) which relies on the MD5 hash function of dubious reputation (!!); that function can be changed on the command-line with the *undocumented* `-md` flag (!!!); the "iteration count" is set by the `enc` command to **1** and cannot be changed (!!!!). This means that the first 16 bytes of the key will be equal to *MD5(password||salt)*, and that's it.
  >
  > **This is quite weak !** Anybody who knows how to write code on a PC can try to crack such a scheme and will be able to "try" several dozens of millions of potential passwords per second (hundreds of millions will be achievable with a GPU). **If you use "openssl enc", make sure your password has very high entropy !** (i.e. higher than usually recommended; aim for 80 bits, at least). Or, preferably, don't use it at all; instead, go for something more robust ([GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/), when doing symmetric encryption for a password, uses a stronger KDF with many iterations of the underlying hash function).

GPG has decades of secure tested use, all the simple mistakes have been avoided/fixed, and could stump a major world superpower if used correctly.